# Could not getting correct text in output after refresh of search results

Tags: java, selenium

This is a site related to find shoe costs. Initially I have entered the text and performed the search and output the number of results obtained.

After selecting a criteria, the search result refresh according to new criteria.
but the output still shows the previous result. I tried with implicit wait but it still shows old result.

This is the code:

```
public void openBrowser() 
{
    StaticData.driver.get("http://laceup.io/phase2");
}

public void homeSearchAndClick() 
{
    System.out.println("In home search");
    StaticData.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='search_field']")).sendKeys("Nike");
    StaticData.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/button")).click();
}

// Function to search by FEMALE gender

public void searchForFemale() 
{
    System.out.println("Gender: Female clicked");
    StaticData.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/label/span")).click();
}

public void filterSearchCount() 
{
    StaticData.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String searchCount = StaticData.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='show_query']/h2")).getText();
    System.out.println("Filter search count: " + searchCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that a     `driver.navigate().refresh();` used in the method `filterSearchCount()` do the trick. Even so, I've noticed that the Nike checkbox for filter isn't checked. In this way, the program will display `Filter search count: 1919 RESULTS` (1918 from Nike + 1 from Warrior)

If you want the exact result for Nike- woman you should check also Nike in the filer area, as I've told you before that the site doesn't check it automatically even if you have been written Nike in the Search Textbox.

Comment: why do you use StaticData.driver.findElement instead of just driver.findElement ?

Comment: thats not the case. Search result is not men+woman. On this site, if you select different gender, checkboxes work as radio buttons. Means selecting Woman will automatically unselect Men.

Comment: any other alternative with the way i followed? other than using page Object Factory?

Comment: what exact number should be displayed? 1918 or 6158? i'm asking you because the 1918 appears for women- nike when it's not checked from the filter and 6158 appears when i'm checking the checkbox.

Comment: ideally accroding to what my criteria it should be 1918

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to fetch the number of results for "Nike" for Women gender there is another way to do it. You can toggle the Ladies beforehand on the homepage itself.

[image]

FYI, I'm using PageObjectFactory to simplify your code

**Phase2Page.java - Page Object Factory for your Home Page**

```
public class Phase2Page {
    WebDriver driver;

    public Phase2Page(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='search_field']")
    WebElement searchField;

    @FindBy (xpath = "html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/button")
    WebElement searchBtn;

    @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='filter_gender_ul']/li[2]")
    WebElement LadiesToggle;

    public void homeSearchAndClick() {
        System.out.println("In home search");
        LadiesToggle.click();
        searchField.sendKeys("Nike");
        searchBtn.click();
    }
}
```

**SearchPage.java - Page Object Factory for Search Page**

```
public class SearchPage {
    WebDriver driver;


    @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='show_query']/h2")
    WebElement searchCount;

    public SearchPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 50),this);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "html/body/div[1]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/label/span")
    WebElement femaleCheckbox;


    // Function to search by FEMALE gender
    public void searchForFemale() {
        System.out.println("Gender: Female clicked");
        femaleCheckbox.click();
    }

    public void filterSearchCount() {
        String count = searchCount.getText();
        System.out.println("Filter search count: " + count);
    }
}
```

**Test1.java - Your Actual Test for execution**

```
public class Test1 {
    WebDriver driver;

    public void openBrowser() {
        driver.get("http://laceup.io/phase2");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSearch(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium Webdriver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        openBrowser();
        Phase2Page objHome = new Phase2Page(driver);
        SearchPage objSearch = new SearchPage(driver);
        objHome.homeSearchAndClick();
        objSearch.filterSearchCount();
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code worked when i used thread.sleep in filterSearchCount().